# NavigationMixin.Navigate Not Focusing on the correct subtab

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate, service-console

I have a lwc component which calls the below method after save is successful :

```
navigateToEventRecordPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.eventRecordId,
                //objectApiName: 'Event',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
```

This will open the Event Record Page as a Subtab as I am on the Salesforce Console App. However, after the Event record subtab is opened, it focuses to its previous already opened subtab.

For Example : I have Subtab1, SubTab2, SubTab3, Event Subtab. Once the above method is executed, it opens Event Subtab and quickly after that goes to SubTab3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [SALESFORCE CONSOLE APIS (NAVIGATION ITEM API, WORKSPACE API, UTILITY BAR API) IN LIGHTNING WEB COMPONENT USING AURA AND LIGHTNING MESSAGE CHANNEL](https://salesforcediaries.com/2021/04/10/salesforce-console-apis-in-lightning-web-component/) as LWC does not have that capability at the moment.

Steps to follow:-

- Create a message channel to communicate with aura and lwc
- Create a service aura component without ui which subscribe to lightning message fired from lwc
- fire lightning message channel from lwc and pass the data with event
- handle the message in aura to open a subtab and focus on it
- Place the service aura component on the page where you have placed lwc